# How does global scope differ in node.js compared to in browsers (with specific example)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've run into an issue with Kyle Simpson's excellent "You don't know JS" book on this & Object Prototypes.

[OReilly link](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033738.do).

[Official GitHub link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md).

The text of the book is included at the GitHub link if you'd like to read for complete context as to what's going on.

Here's the code in question:

```
if (!Function.prototype.softBind) {
  Function.prototype.softBind = function(obj) {
    var fn = this,
      curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
      bound = function bound() {
        if (this === global) {console.log('this is global')}
        console.log(this);
        return fn.apply(
          (!this ||
          (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
          this === window) ||
          (typeof global !== "undefined" &&
          this === global)
          ) ? obj : this,
          curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
        );
      };
    bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
    return bound;
  };
}

function foo() {
  console.log("name: " + this.name);
}

var obj = { name: 'obj'};
var obj2 = { name: 'obj2'};
var obj3 = { name: 'obj3'};

var fooOBJ = foo.softBind(obj);

fooOBJ(); // name: obj

obj2.foo = foo.softBind(obj);
obj2.foo(); // name: obj2
fooOBJ.call(obj3); // name: obj3

setTimeout(obj2.foo, 10); // name: obj (only in browser, name: undefined if in node)
```

For the purposes of this question, I'm only interested in the output of the final line of code, which as the comments show print 'name: obj' in a browser, but 'name: undefined' in node.

Can someone explain the how's and why's of this difference? And is there a change that can be made to the softBind function that will cause the code to work the same in both environments?

Comment: running node v0.10.26

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from logging the value of `this` inside `bound`, when the function is called as `setTimeout` callback, `this` is set to a special timeout object:

```
{ _idleTimeout: 10,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idleStart: 1417462313179,
  _monotonicStartTime: 36214497,
  _onTimeout: [Function: bound],
  _repeat: false }
```

I.e. it does **not** refer to the global object, unlike `setTimeout` in browsers. That's why

```
(typeof global !== "undefined" && this === global)
```

is not fulfilled and `this` of `foo` is set to the timeout object, not `obj`.

Comment: Ok, but why does node do this? Thanks for the answer, but just wondering why this behavior is different from what happens in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I can't give you a definite answer, but keep in mind that `setTimeout` is not part of the ECMAScript specification. It's provided by the browser and only formalized recently as part of HTML5. However, the specification does not dictate what `this` should refer to. And actually, the fact that `this` refers to the global object is seen as disadvantage, which is why this behavior is disabled in strict mode.

Comment: Not the revelation that I was hoping for, but clarification has been provided. Thank you very much!

Comment: Clarification: the HTML spec **does** in fact dictate that the `this` inside the function invoked by a `setTimeout(..)` should always be the global. All browsers will/should adhere to this predictably. Node however is not bound by the HTML spec, and therefore is allowed to have, and indeed has, their own implementation of `setTimeout(..)` that works differently, as stated. :/